# how to show submenu with sitemap in asp .net?

Tags: asp.net

how to show submenu with sitemap in asp .net?

where is wrong?

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" StartingNodeOffset="-2" ShowStartingNode="false" StartFromCurrentNode="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent"
            DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" 
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
            StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
            EnableViewState="False"
            staticdisplaylevel = "2"
            dynamicdisplaylevel = "2"
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1.2em" ForeColor="#666666" 
            StaticSubMenuIndent="30px">
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="LimeGreen" ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
            <DynamicItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Text") %>
            </DynamicItemTemplate>
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="LimeGreen" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Menu>

 <siteMapNode url="~/hello.aspx" title="Start"  description="" >
          <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home" description="" />
          <siteMapNode url="~/Daily_Transaction.aspx" title="Pay fee"  description="" />
          <siteMapNode url="~/EditCompanyMaster.aspx" title="Update Company Name"  description="" />
          <siteMapNode url="~/Report_Selection.aspx" title="Report"  description="">
            <siteMapNode url="~/DailyReport.aspx" title="Daily Report"  description="" />
          </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `StartFromCurrentNode="false"` attribute on the SiteMapDataSource.